# How can i put other items in navbar into the right-side while the others are in the left-side?

Tags: bootstrapping

Below is my code snippet:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <nav class="navbar  navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">This is a LOGO </a>
                </div> 

                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                      <li><a href="#" > Abous US </a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" > Contact US </a></li>     
                      <li><a href="#" > Acount </a></li>
                     </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My question:** How can I pull `ABOUT US` and `CONTACT US` items into the right and the `ACOUNT` is in the left?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), you can use navbar-right to pull some elements to the right:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```